# Issue in menu tree for selection and bootstrap navbar

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, navbar

I tried to use the code below for inside downdrop selection, like:

1. Menu

   - Submenu
   - Submenu

     - Sub-submenu
2. Menu

   - Submenu

     - Sub-submenu
     - Sub-submenu

etc ..

I want to use the same function for dropdown menus and also bootstrap navbar (horizon menu).

```
function PagesList($parent_id) 
{
    global $conn;

    $menu = "";
    $sqlquery = " SELECT * FROM pages where p_top='" .$parent_id . "' ORDER BY BINARY p_name ASC";
    $res=mysqli_query($conn,$sqlquery);

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
    {   
        $menu .="<option value = \"".$row['p_id']."\" $sel>";
        $menu .=$row['p_name']."</option>";
        $menu .=PagesList($row['p_id']).""; 
    }

    return $menu;
}
```

Comment: Maybe not an answer to your question, but your method is very query intensive. There are ways to do this in MySQL. This is a good example http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-adjacency-list-tree/

Comment: Can you please describe what is not working correctly with your code ?

Comment: code is working fine basically, but i want output like a structure add -- sub and sub sub ... etc